# Mixed-stategy Nash equilibrium under prospect theory

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, utility

I know that for Expected Utility Theory we have at least one mixed-Strategy Nash equilibrium for finite games, but is there a proof to generalize the existence of NE under prospect theory?
Specifically, I use framing effect in PT to calculate utility and now, I wonder if we have a Mixed-Strategy Nash equilibrium for players.
I also appreciate any reference that discusses games under PT thoroughly.

Comment: This paper considers Nash equilibrium under the assumption of loss aversion: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s001820000038

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my understanding that under prospect theory only utilities will change versus the standard case.  So long as your utility functions, extended to the space of randomizations, are still quasi-concave for all players you will have a Nash equilibrium.

**Theorem**: Let $G=\big(N, (\Delta(S_i), u_i)_{i\in N}\big)$ be a finite (i.e. $|N|< \infty$ and $|S_i|<\infty$ for all $i$) strategic form game where, $u_i : \times_{i \in N} \Delta(S_i) \to \mathbb{R}$ is quasi-concave for all agents.  Then there exists a Nash equilibrium.

*Proof*: By [**Berge's Theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem) best-replies are upper-hemicontinuous and compact-valued for all agents.  By quasiconcavity, these best-replies are convex valued correspondences (to see this, recall that for a quasiconcave function all upper contour sets are convex, hence so too is the argmax as it is the upper contour set of the maximal value).  Hence the joint best-reply map for all agents inherits all of these properties, and thus by Kakutani's fixed point theorem an equilibrium exists. QED

Comment: Thanks, but I can't understand the term "as your utility functions, extended to the space of randomizations...". How can I be sure of this? My utility under PT is similar to "A. Tversky and D. Kahneman" utility function under framing effect.

Comment: @user2032717 For 'traditional' von Neumann-Morgenstern utility, one starts out with payoffs defined over the set of outcomes, i.e. combinations of choice of action.  One then says that this defines a utility over all randomizations as well by assuming that utility is linear with regard to randomizing: if $X$ is a 50-50 gamble between outcomes $A$ and $B$, by hypothesis $U(X) = U(0.5A + 0.5B) = 0.5U(A) + 0.5U(B)$.  This is what I meant by extension.  Now in your case this may be different, but for Nash equilibria, what you need is your utility over gambles to be quasiconcave.

Comment: If you need more help, a good place to be would be if you could explicitly write down what your utility function for each player in the game is, and I can try to help you from there.